# Pandas plot: Is it possible draw other thing than the column names as label?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using this dataframe: https://www.kaggle.com/fivethirtyeight/fivethirtyeight-fandango-dataset it has several columns that I want to plot, tehy are `['RT_norm', 'RT_user_norm', 'Metacritic_norm', 'Metacritic_user_nom', 'IMDB_norm', 'Fandango_Stars']`

When I do any kind of plot with Pandas, the labels are the column labels (Duh!)

```
df.head().plot.bar(x='FILM', y=marc, figsize=(10,8), grid=True)

plt.title('Calificaciones de Películas por Sitio')
plt.ylabel('Calificación')
plt.xlabel('Película')
```

[image]

Is there any chance I can change the labels to be something else? I dunno... instead of `RT_norm` I'd want `Rotten Tomatoes Normalized`, or the only correct answer is to change the column names in the dataframe? I tried using `yticks` and `ylabel` parameters, but they just don't work as I want.

Comment: what about temporarily renaming the columns? e.g. `df.rename(columns={'RT_norm ': 'Rotten Tomatoes Normalized'}).head().plot.bar(x='FILM', y=marc, figsize=(10,8), grid=True)`

Comment: Hummm interesting, I forgot if there's no `inplace=True` that won't change the original dataframe, this is very clever.

Comment: And yes, that answer is also correct. There are so many ways to paraphrase a question, I never find that one

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change the legend labels using `plt.legend(labels=..)` :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'FILM':range(100),
                   'y1':np.random.uniform(0,1,100),
                   'y2':np.random.uniform(0,1,100)})
df.head().plot.bar(x='FILM', y=['y1','y2'], figsize=(10,8), grid=True)
plt.legend(labels=['bar1','bar2'])
```